# Show objects in string array side by side in a text Area using java

Tags: java, arraylist

I wanted to read specific columns written in my text file and show this specific columns onto my text Area side by side.  I manage to read the desired columns and show them to my text area using the codes below:

```
try
    {
        ArrayList<String> totalResult1 = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> totalResult2 = new ArrayList<String>();
        [enter image description here][1]ArrayList<String> totalResult3 = new ArrayList<String>();
                try
                {
                    FileInputStream fStream = new FileInputStream("hubo\\" + "table" + ".txt");
                    DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fStream);
                    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(in));
                    String strLine;

                    while((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)
                    {
                        strLine = strLine.trim();

                            if((strLine.length()!=0) && (strLine.charAt(0) !='#')) 
                            {
                                String[] employee = strLine.split("\\s+");
                                totalResult1.add(employee[0]);
                                totalResult2.add(employee[1]);
                                totalResult3.add(employee[2]);
                            }   

                    }

                    for(String s1 : totalResult1)
                    {   
                        showArea.append(s1.toString() + "\n");                  
                    }   

                    for(String s2 : totalResult2)
                    {   
                        showArea.append("\t" + "\t" + s2.toString() + "\n");                    
                    }

                    in.close();
                    }           
                    catch (Exception e1)
                    {

                    }                           

            }
            catch(Exception e1)
            {

            }
```

This is my result

```
   Alex Santos
   Troy Smith
   John Love

                Married
                Single
                Married
```

My desired results are this:

```
   Alex Santos   Married
   Troy Smith    Single
   John Love     Married
```

I want to show to my text Area both of my columns side by side, can anyone point me to the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is close, but not quite. When you append the employe names from `totalResult1` you go to a new line each time. So when you add values from the second list, you are already bellow the names. To create a table like display, you would need to add values from each list at the same time:

```
for(int i = 0; i < totalResult1.size(); i++){
      showArea.append(totalResult1.get(i) + "\t\t");  
      showArea.append(totalResult2.get(i) + "\n");
}
```

The should do the trick. But in general, when you want a table you shouldn't use a text area, you can use a table control instead.

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Comment: I've solve the problem thanks for the solution tomtzook